# Refresh a div with PHP variable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to refresh a div every second with a PHP variable using Jquery.

I have a simple PHP file with a variable date:

```
<?php 
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
?>
```

I have a HTML file with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        function request() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "date.php",
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#result').html(json.date);
                }             
            });              
        }

        setTimeout(request, 1000);
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the result is a blank page. I can not make it work. I would like your help.

I would like to refresh every second a PHP variable using Jquery.

Comment: The PHP code isn't *outputting* anything.  Did you forget an `echo`?  Also, that value isn't JSON, so you don't need to parse it as JSON in the client-side code.

Comment: You also need to use `setInterval`, in order to have the updates you wanted.

Comment: Making the page (bearing in mind multiple users could have it open at once) request something every second is a good way to severely overload your server. If you just want to display the current time, use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print date variable:

```
<?php 
  $date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
  echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: Is not there a way without printing the content?

<?php
include 'date.php';
echo json_encode($date, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>

That code works without print the content, I would like to refresh every second.

Comment: check comments - specially @ADyson's.

Comment: @Victor `That code works without print the content`...what do you mean? `echo` prints content. How do you expect the browser to see what PHP produced if you don't echo it? That doesn't make any sense.